# NPDock - service unavailable

Tags: rna, docking, webservice

NPDock service http://genesilico.pl/NPDock/ is unavailable, at least that's the message that shows after you try to submit a job. It's been like this for the last few weeks. Contact email address provided on the page also doesn't work. Does NPDock work for anyone else?

Comment: I also got the same error message; the website also says "Please run max. 5 jobs at the same time. If you need to run more jobs, please consider installing NPDock (DARS-RNP) locally.", but I couldn't find any link to the actual software.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question that should be asked of the tool's developers and not a general bioinformatics issue.

Comment: Sorry but we can't help with this sort of thing.

Comment: Ok, now it's fixed.